# PHP Remove everything after and including .html in a web address string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove everything after and including '.html' in a web address string. Current (failing) code is:

```
$input = 'http://example.com/somepage.html?foo=bar&baz=x';
$result = preg_replace("/(.html)[^.html]+$/i",'',$input);
```

Desired outcome:

```
value of $result is 'http://example.com/somepage'
```

Some other examples of $input that should lead to same value $result:

```
http://example.com/somepage
http://example.com/somepage.html
http://example.com/somepage.html?url=http://example.com/index.html
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regular expresson is wrong, it would only match strings ending with `<one char> "html" <one or more chars matching ., h, t, m or l>`. Since `preg_replace` just returns the string "as-is" if there was no match, you'd be fine with matching the literal `.html` and ignoring anything after it:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\.html.*/', '', $input);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead?

Comment: Won't the path element in the returned array still contain .html?

Comment: It will, but a simply rtrim will remove it, and you solve the problem just with built in functions.

Comment: Doesn't parse_url just use regex under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have issues with the syntax for preg_replace() then you can also use explode():

```
$input = explode(".html", $input);
$result = $input[0];
```

Comment: I like the simplicity in this. (will break with http://example.com/somedir.html/somefile.html, and yes that is a possible url haha)

Comment: No -- the ".html" serves as the delimiter so the above solution would not break in your example.  It would be the same if you were to treat "," as the delimiter in a CSV string.